# Select top 3 items of a List using lambdaj

Tags: java, collections, lambdaj

I want to select the top 3 items of a java List.

I know how to sort the List (please see the code), but I don't know how to select the top 3 entries of this list having the highest values (**[3.0, 5.5, 7.2]**).

I guess I could use subList(), but I want to know if there is a way to do this in lambdaj.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(5.5,1.5,7.2,3.0,0.5);
        System.out.println(list);
        List<Double> sortedList = sort(list,on(Double.class).doubleValue());
        System.out.println(sortedList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `subList` **is** the way you do it (but have in mind that it returns a list _view_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `lambdaj`? This is a simple enough task that can be done like this:

```
List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(5.5,1.5,7.2,3.0,0.5);
System.out.println(list);

List<Double> sortedList = sort(list, on(Double.class).doubleValue());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedList.subList(0, 2).toArray()));
```

`lambdaj` has no real use here. Since you are only asking to get parts of the list, and not to modify it in any way, using `List`s built in method is the best solution.

If you *really* want to use `lambdaj`, `LambdaList` has a `subList()` method, but that is **exactly** the same as the one in Java SE's `List` interface.